# Android: Camera preview is tilted

Tags: android, android-camera

I have made a program implementing Camera on surface view.

In landscape mode, the preview is correct, but in portrait mode the preview is tilted 180 degrees, it is not coming upright.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with your app always being in landscape mode, then you should add this line to your manifest and it will get rid of your problem:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

However, if you do want to want a portrait mode application then, you can add this to your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

as long as you add the `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` line to your activity (provided you check for android version greater than or equal to Froyo.